# Where to define the name for @CircuitBreaker(name = BACKEND, fallbackMethod = "fallback")?

Tags: java, spring, resilience4j

I'm trying to use the Spring Boot annotations for Resilience4j.

When I use the annotation `@CircuitBreaker(name = BACKEND, fallbackMethod = "fallback")`

my Intellij shows red for the circuitBreaker-name BACKEND.

How can/should I define a circuitBreaker which can be recoginzed by the name in the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the CircuitBreaker must be be a string.